# PHP Sum Up the value of textbox

Tags: php, textbox, sum

How to sum up the value of textbox and display it. For example the value of textbox is 1 and 2 and the other textbox will display 3. Please help me solve the problem. Thank you~

```
  $name = $row['Name'];
  $data2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblstockmgt WHERE ItemName ='$name'") or die(mysql_error());
  while($row2= mysql_fetch_array( $data2 )) 
  {
    echo "<td align='right'><input type='text' name='txt[]' value='".$row2['Price']."'/></td>";
  }
```

Comment: in which text box the total will be displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a varabile `$total` and always incrase it, and after the loop, write the value into a textbox:

```
$total = 0;
 while($row2= mysql_fetch_array( $data2 )) {
    echo "<td align='right'><input type='text' name='txt[]' value='".$row2['Price']."'/></td>";
    $total += $row2['Price'];
}
?>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Total: <input type="textbox" name="total" value="<?php echo $total; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
```

- Avoid to sql injections, let's escape your strings in your query.
- Use mysqli or PDO instead mysql functions,because mysql functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $total = 0;
 while($row2= mysql_fetch_array( $data2 )) 
 {
    echo "<td align='right'><input type='text' name='txt[]' value='".$row2['Price']."'/>   </td>";
    $total += $row2['Price'];
 }
 echo "<td align='right'><input type='text' name='txt[]' value='".$total."'/>   </td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery or a variable in your loop.
Loop php summing

```
$sum = 0;
 while($row2= mysql_fetch_array( $data2 )) 
      {
        echo "<td align='right'><input type='text' name='txt[]' value='".$row2['Price']."'/></td>";
        $sum += $row2['Price'];
 }
echo $sum;
```

Jquery version

```
 <div class="section">
        while($row2= mysql_fetch_array( $data2 )) 
          {
            echo "<td align='right'><input type='text' name='txt[]' value='".$row2['Price']."'/></td>";
        }
        <div id="mysum"></div>
        </div>

        <script>
            $('.section').each(function(){
                  var totalPoints = 0;
                  $(this).find('input').each(function(i,n){
                    totalPoints += parseInt($(n).val(),10); 
                  });
                  alert(totalPoints);
                   $('#mysum').html(totalPoints);
                });
        </script>
```

PDO Version, please transform your script from deprecated mysql_fetch etc. example

```
try {
    $name= mysql_real_escape_string($row['Name']);
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tablename', 'user', 'password');
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tblstockmgt WHERE ItemName:=this');
    $stmt->bindValue(':this', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $sum = 0;
    if ($stmt->rowCount() == 0) {
        echo "No data";
        die();
    }
    foreach ($results as $result) {
       echo "<td align='right'><input type='text' name='txt[]' value='".$result['Price']."'/></td>";
       $sum += $result['Price'];

    }
        echo $sum;
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    die($ex->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Why do you use jquery for this?

Comment: I feel like using more client side summing. It all depends on the data range if the loop is short you can use the variable sum, idc. An alternative is always nice

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
$sum=0;

while($row2= mysql_fetch_array( $data2 ))
          {
            $sum += $row2['Price'];
            echo "<td align='right'><input type='text' name='txt[]' value='".$sum."'/></td>";

          }
```